# How to programmatically invert screen colors in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, for example, you can use Super-M to invert the screen colors (requires desktop effects, see [1]). Other OSes have similar abilities, although I'm not really concerned with anything other than Linux.

Which API should I look into if I want to write a simple program that, when run, inverts the screen colors?

The language that I use the API from doesn't particularly matter to me. I am familiar enough with C/C++/Bash/Perl/Python that I can hack this up in whatever language has the easiest access to this API. Working on Ubuntu is required, working on other similar *nixes is not terribly important.

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts#Desktop%20Effects%20enabled%20shortcuts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [xcalib](http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/) to do what you want.

For example, a simple bash script to invert the screen colors would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcalib -invert -alter
```

Comment: `xrandr-invert-colors` for the win here. If you're wanting to do it programatically, just look at the source of this application. I'm not sure if it was around ten years ago...

Answer (score 1):

Here are scripts and instructions for shifting colors using compton: https://github.com/vn971/linux-color-inversion

Comment: I don't have the ability to test this at the moment, but it looks nice. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

[`xrandr-invert-colors`](https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors) worked out of the box for me.

`xcalib` does not work for me using xorg and a tiling window manager, with an external display and gives me the following error: "Unable to get a display calibration".

Credit to [Imat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552037/how-to-programmatically-invert-screen-colors-in-linux#comment105274837_3554513).