# How to programmatically invert screen colors on Mac

Tags: macos

How can I write a script to run on Mac that inverts screen colors?

Similar to [How to programmatically invert screen colors in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552037/how-to-programmatically-invert-screen-colors-in-linux), but unfortunately xcalib works on Windows and Linux but not Mac as far as I can tell.

EDIT: I have a partial solution. I found a way dump all of my settings, before and after inverting screen colors:

```
$ mkdir before && mkdir after && cd before
$ for d in $(defaults domains | sed 's/,//g'); do defaults read $d > $d; done
$ cd ../after
$ # System Preferences > Universal Access > Display > White on Black
$ for d in $(defaults domains | sed 's/,//g'); do defaults read $d > $d; done
$ diff -r before after
diff -r before/com.apple.CoreGraphics after/com.apple.CoreGraphics
3c3
<     DisplayUseInvertedPolarity = 0;
---
>     DisplayUseInvertedPolarity = 1;
diff -r before/com.apple.universalaccess after/com.apple.universalaccess
5c5
<     whiteOnBlack = 0;
---
>     whiteOnBlack = 1;
```

So now I know what settings are responsible for screen inversion. But when I try the obvious,

```
$ defaults write com.apple.universalaccess whiteOnBlack -int 1
$ defaults write com.apple.CoreGraphics DisplayUseInvertedPolarity -int 1
```

Nothing happens. Presumably whatever programs use these values need to be told to reload them (since the examples from e.g. [dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) need to kill Finder to take effect). But I'm not sure what apps those would be, or whether this is the correct solution anyway.

Comment: To remind myself to look up from my screen at regular intervals while I'm coding. Suggestions?

Comment: I'd guess that the WindowServer process needs a nudge to notice the setting change, but I don't know how.  If you actually kill the WindowServer, I think it will kill any GUI apps too.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried killall WindowServer -HUP and it caused me to log out. Definitely not the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet of Apple Script will do it:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 28 using {control down, option down, command down}
end tell
```

This uses the Control-Option-Cmd-8 shortcut (keycode 28 is the number 8). You'll have to figure out how to call it from whatever you need...

Comment: This appears to cause glitches if I'm typing while I invoke the script. Is there a solution which doesn't involve simulating keystrokes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... I don't know much about Mac GUI programming. Presumably this keyboard shortcut is calling some other underlying call, but I don't know.

Comment: For this to work you must have the box checked in  System Preferences > Universal Access > Enable Access for Assistive Devices

Answer (score 1):

You can try to perfect this snippet that returns the current status with GUI scripting. The  value seems to be read-only and trying to set it to 1 or 0 fails.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    launch
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    tell application "System Events"
        return value of checkbox "Invert colors" of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
  activate
  reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
  tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click the checkbox "Invert colors" of window "Accessibility"
  end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Monterey or newer it’s now possible to toggle Smart and Classic Invert using the new Shortcuts app. Search for "Invert" in the Action list when creating a new shortcut.