# How do I invert screen colors in Mac with a command line?

Tags: bash, applescript, accessibility, osascript

I would like to invert the screen colors with a script (osascript, bash, applescript or even with something in C code).

The closest thing I have found is toggle the dark theme.

```
> osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to not dark mode'
```

I tried a lot of things, but without any luck. I was able to change the defaults file, but I want the changes to apply without logging out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/222448 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6511304/6770384

Comment: Either osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to true'  or osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to false' works on OS X Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026). Neither requires a logout